# Breadth First Search Javascript (Algorithm or input)

Tags: javascript, breadth-first-search

Its just supposed to be a breadth-first-search, labeling parents as it goes along. When it finished it traces those parents back to the start to make a path.

The map is just an array of these tiles

```
function Tile(x, y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    //for BFS
    this.px = 0;
    this.py = 0;
    this.visited = false;

    this.is = " ";

    this.n = null;
    this.e = null;
    this.s = null;
    this.w = null;
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out if it is my algorithm or my starting data.

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me troubleshoot this Object or clear it as correct.

```
    function FakeBFS(){
    var me = this;

    this.get_path = function(sx, sy, ex, ey, map){
        var x = sx;
        var y = sy;
        var unfinished = [{"x":sx, "y":sy}];

        //walk until we can't or we reach our destination
        while(unfinished.length && x != ex && y != ey){

            var new_location = unfinished.shift();

            x = new_location.x;
            y = new_location.y;

            //if we haven't been here...
            if(map.tiles[x][y].visited == false){

                console.log("\n\nlooking for path from:"+x+","+y+" to:"+ex+","+ey);
                var nesw_array = new Array(
                                            [x,y+1], //n
                                            [x+1,y], //e
                                            [x,y-1], //s
                                            [x-1,y]);//w
                                            console.log(nesw_array);

                //add all the vertices we care about to unfinished
                for(var nesw=0; nesw<4; nesw++){
                    var vx = nesw_array[nesw][0];
                    var vy = nesw_array[nesw][1];
                    console.log(nesw_array[nesw]);
                    if( (map.tiles[vx][vy].is == " "
                    ||  map.tiles[vx][vy].is == "H")
                    &&  map.tiles[vx][vy].visited == false){
                        console.log("parenting["+nesw+"]"+map.tiles[vx][vy].x+","+map.tiles[vx][vy].y+" to:"+x+","+y);
                        //set the route we took to get here
                        map.tiles[vx][vy].px = x;
                        map.tiles[vx][vy].py = y;
                        unfinished.push({"x":map.tiles[vx][vy].x, "y":map.tiles[vx][vy].y});
                    }
                }
                //visit this vertex
                map.tiles[x][y].visited = true;
            }

            console.log("END LOOP looking for path from:"+x+","+y+" to:"+ex+","+ey);
        }

        //walk back to start for our path
        var path = Array();
        if(x == ex && y == ey){
            while(x != sx && y != sy){
                path.push({"x":x,"y":y});
                console.log(x+","+y);
                x = map.tiles[x][y].px;
                y = map.tiles[x][y].py;
            }
            path.push({"x":x,"y":y});
            console.log("Path:"+util.inspect(path));
            return path;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I made some sample data and it is basically having the same problem which is hard to pin down.
In the code below "me" refers to the Map() object.

```
function TestMap(){
    var me = this;
    this.paths = new Array();
    //width and height
    this.size = 10;
    this.num_tiles = this.size*this.size;
    //we can't build on the edge
    this.start = 1;
    this.end = this.size-this.start;

    //
    //
    //tiles
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    this.tiles = new Array();

    //
    //
    //print
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    this.print = function(){
        var mapscii = "";
        for(var y=this.end; y>-1; y--){
            for(var x=0; x<this.size; x++){

                    mapscii += this.tiles[x][y].is;

            }
            mapscii += "\n";
        }
        console.log(mapscii);
    }

    //
    //
    //setup the tile array and the associations
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.init_map = function (){
        for(var x=0; x<me.size; x++){
            me.tiles[x] = new Array();
            for(var y=0; y<me.size; y++){
                var t = new Tile(x, y);

                //draw bounds
                if(x==0 || y==0 || x==me.size-1 || y==me.size-1){
                    t.is = "#";
                }
                me.tiles[x][y] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    //
    //
    //setup the tile array and the associations
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.fake_map = function (){
        var fake_rooms = [      [2,2]
                            ,   [2,3]
                            ,   [3,2]
                            //, [3,3]

                            //, [5,2]
                            ,   [5,3]
                            ,   [6,2]
                            ,   [6,3]
                        ];

        var fake_doors = [
                                [3,3]
                            ,   [5,2]
                        ];

        for(var x=0; x<fake_rooms.length; x++){
            me.tiles[fake_rooms[x][0]][fake_rooms[x][1]].is = ".";
        }
        for(var x=0; x<fake_doors.length; x++){
            me.tiles[fake_doors[x][0]][fake_doors[x][1]].is = "H";
        }
    }

    this.fake_place_paths = function(){
        var bfs = new BFS();

        me.paths[0] = bfs.get_path(
                        3,3,
                        5,2,
                        me
            );
    }

    this.mark_paths = function(){
        for(var i=0; i<me.paths.length; i++){
            console.log(me.paths);
            var thispath = me.paths[i];
            console.log("["+i+"]"+thispath.x+","+thispath.y);
            me.tiles[thispath.x][thispath.y].is = "+";
        }
    }

    this.init_map();
    this.fake_map();
    this.fake_place_paths();
    this.print();
    this.mark_paths();
}
```

This is what the "fake map" looks like when it's printed.

# = Bounds

. = Room

H = Door

```
##########
#        #
#        #
#        #
#        #
#        #
# .H ..  #
# .. H.  #
#        #
##########
```

Here's my debugging output.

```
C:\Users\trans\Documents\JS>node test_bfs.js


looking for path from:3,3 to:5,2
[ [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 3 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]
[ 3, 4 ]
parenting[0]3,4 to:3,3
[ 4, 3 ]
parenting[1]4,3 to:3,3
[ 3, 2 ]
[ 2, 3 ]
END LOOP looking for path from:3,3 to:5,2


looking for path from:3,4 to:5,2
[ [ 3, 5 ], [ 4, 4 ], [ 3, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ] ]
[ 3, 5 ]
parenting[0]3,5 to:3,4
[ 4, 4 ]
parenting[1]4,4 to:3,4
[ 3, 3 ]
[ 2, 4 ]
parenting[3]2,4 to:3,4
END LOOP looking for path from:3,4 to:5,2


looking for path from:4,3 to:5,2
[ [ 4, 4 ], [ 5, 3 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 3, 3 ] ]
[ 4, 4 ]
parenting[0]4,4 to:4,3
[ 5, 3 ]
[ 4, 2 ]
parenting[2]4,2 to:4,3
[ 3, 3 ]
END LOOP looking for path from:4,3 to:5,2


looking for path from:3,5 to:5,2
[ [ 3, 6 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ] ]
[ 3, 6 ]
parenting[0]3,6 to:3,5
[ 4, 5 ]
parenting[1]4,5 to:3,5
[ 3, 4 ]
[ 2, 5 ]
parenting[3]2,5 to:3,5
END LOOP looking for path from:3,5 to:5,2


looking for path from:4,4 to:5,2
[ [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 4 ], [ 4, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ] ]
[ 4, 5 ]
parenting[0]4,5 to:4,4
[ 5, 4 ]
parenting[1]5,4 to:4,4
[ 4, 3 ]
[ 3, 4 ]
END LOOP looking for path from:4,4 to:5,2


looking for path from:2,4 to:5,2
[ [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 1, 4 ] ]
[ 2, 5 ]
parenting[0]2,5 to:2,4
[ 3, 4 ]
[ 2, 3 ]
[ 1, 4 ]
parenting[3]1,4 to:2,4
END LOOP looking for path from:2,4 to:5,2
END LOOP looking for path from:4,4 to:5,2


looking for path from:4,2 to:5,2
[ [ 4, 3 ], [ 5, 2 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]
[ 4, 3 ]
[ 5, 2 ]
parenting[1]5,2 to:4,2
[ 4, 1 ]
parenting[2]4,1 to:4,2
[ 3, 2 ]
END LOOP looking for path from:4,2 to:5,2
##########
#        #
#        #
#        #
#        #
#        #
# .H ..  #
# .. H.  #
#        #
##########

[ false ]
[0]undefined,undefined
C:\Users\trans\Documents\JS\testmap.js:102
                        me.tiles[thispath.x][thispath.y].is = "+";
                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
    at TestMap.mark_paths (C:\Users\trans\Documents\JS\testmap.js:102:24)
    at new TestMap (C:\Users\trans\Documents\JS\testmap.js:110:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\trans\Documents\JS\test_bfs.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
```

Comment: maybe you could add some data as well to make the part working.

Comment: What is the me object in this line: for(var i=0; i<me.paths.length; i++){

Comment: "me" is a generic placeholder I'm using inside my objects to keep a reference to the parent object when "this" changes scope.

I've been just using it exclusively to keep from accidentally referencing the wrong "this".

It is the Map() object.

Comment: I've updated all the code to what I'm working with now... I removed as many object references as I could, moved to primitive data values for evaluation... I'm still not able to crack it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was with my conditions for leaving the loop and also modifying the variable I was using to reference something before I had gotten that data.

```
           .......................

    //walk until we can't or we reach our destination
    while(unfinished.length){

        var new_location = unfinished.shift();

        x = new_location.x;
        y = new_location.y;

        if(x == ex && y == ey){
            unfinished.length = 0;
            continue;
        }

    ..........................

    //walk back to start for our path
    var path = Array();
    if(x == ex && y == ey){
        console.log("here");
        while(!(x == sx && y == sy)){
            path.push({"x":x,"y":y});
            console.log(x+","+y);
            //temporary to not screw up reference
            var tempx = map.tiles[x][y].px;
            tempx = map.tiles[x][y].px;
            y = map.tiles[x][y].py;
            x = tempx;
            console.log(x+","+y);
        }
        path.push({"x":x,"y":y});
        return path;
    }
    return false;
```